# Need barcode scanner for Linux Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: linux, compatibility, ubuntu-9.04, barcode-scanner

dear all..i have made my project using Linux Ubuntu 9.04 OS.i want to use barcode scanner for my project.Can you tell me what's barcode scanner that compatible with this OS.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly all modern (last few years) barcode scanners that plug in via USB or PS/2 (e.g. **NOT** serial) are compatible with all operating systems.

When connected to a machine, they get detected as a standard keyboard. All the "magic" happens within the unit itself, so, you just point it to a barcode and it will input the numbers/characters/pattern in the exact place of the cursor, as if you typed them on a keyboard.

FYI - The only difference between new scanners is usually that some send a line return after processing and others don't, as well as speed of the unit.

Comment: whether by using the barcode scanner the latest edition we still have to use a barcode scanner driver?

Comment: @klox, no driver should be needed, the computer should see them as standard keyboards.

Comment: Exactly the answer I would have given, as far as Linux sees it it will use a generic keyboard driver (Same in Windows).

Comment: Note that you may have to use `xinput` etc. to prevent the scanner from acting as "real" keyboard if that interferes with other applications; there are quite a few questions about this on this site and on the unix stackexchange.